# distinct users, get last login info

Tags: sql, t-sql

I found something that I cannot resolve by my self. Lack of problem solving techniques... :(

I need to get result to select each user with his id, and show their last login info,
for example from this table:

```
id      name        loginTime                           logoutTime
3       test        2013-11-25 22:50:00                 null
4       test1       2013-11-20 07:23:18                 null
6       test2       2013-11-19 11:17:22                 null
3       test3       2013-11-27 14:20:54                 null
16      test4       2013-11-09 13:52:21                 null
3       test        2013-12-02 23:07:43                 null
2       test5       2013-11-11 18:15:31                 null
4       test1       2013-11-17 19:13:59                 null
6       test2       2013-11-30 03:10:07                 null
...
```

I need to get:

```
id      name        loginTime                           logoutTime
2       test5       2013-11-11 18:15:31                 null
3       test        2013-12-02 23:07:43                 null
4       test1       2013-11-20 07:23:18                 null
6       test2       2013-11-30 03:10:07                 null
16      test4       2013-11-09 13:52:21                 null
...
```

SO far I have used DISTINCT to distinct users, but there is a problem with getting last date of login per distinct user...

What is the best and proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select max(loginTime), id, name
from your_table
group by id, name
```

Comment: OK, I feel stupid right now... when I saw function max() and group by I was so ashamed... simple function and grouping solved the problem... sorry for bugging you...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, logintime, logouttime a from table where logintime=(select max(logintime) from table b where a.id = b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort them with `row_number()` in a CTE and then filter on the latest in the select:

```
declare @log table (id int, name varchar(10), loginTime datetime, logoutTime datetime);
insert into @log
select 3,       'test',        '2013-11-25 22:50:00',                 null union all
select 4,       'test1',       '2013-11-20 07:23:18',                 null union all
select 6,       'test2',       '2013-11-19 11:17:22',                 null union all
select 3,       'test3',       '2013-11-27 14:20:54',                 null union all
select 16,      'test4',       '2013-11-09 13:52:21',                 null union all
select 3,       'test',        '2013-12-02 23:07:43',                 null union all
select 2,       'test5',       '2013-11-11 18:15:31',                 null union all
select 4,       'test1',       '2013-11-17 19:13:59',                 null union all
select 6,       'test2',       '2013-11-30 03:10:07',                 null


;with yak as
(   select  [r]=row_number()over(partition by name order by loginTime desc), * 
    from @log
)
select * 
from yak 
where r = 1;
```

You can also just `MAX(LoginDate)` as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: thanks mate, but I want to do as simple as possible so post above is perfect... cheers :)